# Sum of the most recent non-null columns (window function with "ignore nulls")

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.9.

In the project I am working on, some most recent records have null columns because that information was not available when that row was created. I have a view that lists the sum of rows that belongs to the members of a group. As of right now, the view shows the sum of the most recent columns, which uses null values if those are the most recent values. For example,

```
table1

group_name | member
-------------------
group1     | Andy
group1     | Bob

table2

name | stat_date | col1 | col2 | col 3
--------------------------------------
Andy | 6/19/13   | null |    1 |     2
Andy | 6/18/13   |  100 |    3 |     5
Bob  | 6/19/13   |   50 |    9 |    12
Bob  | 6/18/13   |  111 |   31 |    51

-- creating view would be something like this... 
create view v_grouped as 
select table1.group_name, stat_date, 
sum(col1) as col1_sum, sum(col2) as col2_sum, sum(col3) as col3_sum
from table1
join table2 on table1.member = table2.name
group by table1.group_name, table2.stat_date;
```

Current view looks like this:

```
group_name | stat_date | col1_sum | col2_sum | col3_sum
-------------------------------------------------------
group1     | 6/19/13   |       50 |       10 |       14
group2     | 6/18/13   |      211 |       34 |       56
```

Instead of 50, 150 would be a closer representation of what the actual group total is, despite lack of data for 6/19. So, I want an output of

```
group_name | stat_date | col1_sum | col2_sum | col3_sum
-------------------------------------------------------
group1     |   6/19/13  |     150 |       10 |       14
group2     |   6/18/13  |     211 |       34 |       56
```

I've been looking at `first_value()` from window functions as a possible function to use. I found that Oracle's `first_value()` supports the `ignore nulls` option which I believe will do what I want (http://psoug.org/definition/FIRST_VALUE.htm). According to this page I linked, about PL/SQL's `first_value()` function:

> If the first value in the result set is NULL then the function returns NULL unless you specify IGNORE NULLS.
>   If you use the IGNORE NULLS parameter then FIRST_VALUE will return the first non-null value found in the result set. (If all
>   values are null then it will return NULL.)
>
> Example Syntax: FIRST_VALUE(expression [INGORE NULLS]) OVER (analytic_clause)

But PostgreSQL's `first_value()` does not support such an option. Is there a way to do this in PostgreSql? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just included the sql script that goes along with the view. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation. You keep writing "most recent columns". Do you add columns in time? What do you mean by "most recent column"?

Comment: In this case, I have stat_date, which I want to use to determine the most recent rows. In this example, there are multiple rows per person, but some of them are more recent than others depending on the stat_date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`this`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_%28aggregate%29) custom aggregate as a postgres variant of `FIRST_VALUE(expression INGORE NULLS)`. Or build your own aggregate with desired behavior.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but the function took too long compared to MySQL version so I just gave up on this. (Will wait until there are more windows function added to postgres!!!)

Comment: I just want to add that while this solution works, it's not as fast as window function!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to describe?

```sql
SELECT sum(col1), sum(col2), sum(col3) FROM table2 WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
```

(although I omitted the join on table1;  that is an exercise for the reader)

Comment: It's kind of like what I want - if col1 is null, then I want the view to take the col1 value from the most recent row where col1 is not null, and sum with other col1 values that are 'most recent non-null' values.

Comment: And even if col1 is not available, I still want to sum up the most recent non-null values for col2 and col3, regardless of whether col1 is null.